# Using PHP to stringify JSON, but having syntax errors

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm utilizing PHP to stringify input from my form to a JSON. It's currently formatting it like this

```
{"name":"asfd","username":"awsf","email":"kean","age":"21","gender":"Male","submit":"Submit"},  
{"name":"asdf","username":"asfd","email":"asdf@asdf","age":"21","gender":"Male","submit":"Submit"},
```

But it should look more like this, right?

```
[
{"name":"asfd","username":"awsf","email":"kean","age":"21","gender":"Male","submit":"Submit"},

{"name":"asdf","username":"asfd","email":"asdf@asdf","age":"21","gender":"Male","submit":"Submit"}
]
```

Here is my current php. What should I do to make it stringify correctly?

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['name'])){
$json_data = json_encode($_GET);
// var_dump($json_data);
$file = file_put_contents('data.json', $json_data."," , FILE_APPEND | 
LOCK_EX);

?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ChangeName(<?php echo("'".$_GET['name']."'") ?>);

    </script>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: So what you're putting into ChangeName is this: `{"name":...},{"name":...},` That doesn't seem right.

Comment: You are encoding an object hence the "{}" and then appending it to the end of the file.

Comment: If you concatenate two JSON strings you don't get another JSON, even if you put a comma between them.

Comment: There is no need for the javascript tag, or the javascript lines, right? Please edit to only include vital details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do this is to read data from the file first, decode it, append the new array to that data and encode it again to json and put it in the file, sort of like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['name']))
{
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('data.json'), true);
    $data[] = $_GET;
    $json_data = json_encode($data);
    $file = file_put_contents('data.json', $json_data);
}
```

Comment: Right, but what's happen when another process want to write when the first is currently decode/append/write? Think that's why they use `LOCK_EX`.

Comment: @Syscall Just use the `LOCK_EX` flag, as it is in the question. I just didn't add it because it was irrelevant to the answer.

Comment: Using `LOCK_EX` will lock the file during reading, or writing, not during whole process. - It was just a note - But it's a good answer to the question ;)